# Stuck with this differential equation question, not getting the correct answer.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that, in order to buy a house, you obtain a mortgage. If the lender advertises an annual interest rate $r$, your debt $D$ will increase exponentially according to the simple O.D.E.
$$\frac{dD}{dt}=rD.$$

If you pay your debt at a rate of $P$ (continuous annual rate), the evolution of your debt will then (under assumptions of continual compounding and payment) obey the linear differential equation

$$\frac{dD}{dt}=rD−P.$$

Using this model, answer the following question:

> If initial amount of the mortgage is for $400,000$, the annual interest rate is $5\%$ , and you pay at a rate of $40,000$ every year, how many years will it take you to pay off the debt?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you show your work so we can see where your approach is failing?

Comment: Okay, so I started solving this question as follows

dD/dt - rD = -P
then I solved for the integrating factor which came out to be exp(-rt)
then putting it back and using it 
d(D*exp(-rt)) = -P Integral(exp(-rt))dt
after integrating I got
D*exp(-rt) = (P/r)*exp(-rt) + C 
now I'm getting stuck while caclulating the constant.
at t=0 we get C= D-P/r 
So what do I do now? Assume D as the original 400000 or use it as it is, if I'm using as it is I'm getting nowhere

Comment: At $t=0$, you're 400,000 in debt, so use $D=400 000$ as your initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

The first differential equation:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}=rD$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}-rD=0$$
Let's define $\mu(t):=\exp\left(\int -r \mathrm{d}t\right)=\exp(-rt)$, and multiply both sides with it:
$$\exp(-rt)\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}-\exp(-rt)rD=0$$
By the product rule: $(f\cdot g)'=f' \cdot g+f\cdot g'$, we can see that the LHS can be written as:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg(D \exp(-rt) \bigg)=0$$
Now we can integrate both sides with respect to $t$ to get:
$$D \exp(-rt)=C$$
$$D(t)=C\exp(rt)$$
The second one:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}=rD-P$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}-rD=-P$$
Define the $\mu(t)$ the same way as before, and multiple both sides with it. Now the LHS will be again the derivate ot $D \mu(t)$:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg(D \exp(-rt) \bigg)=-P\exp(-rt)$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$D \exp(-rt)=\frac{-P}{-r}\exp(-rt)+C$$
$$D(t)=\frac{P}{r}+C\exp(rt)$$
We know that $P=40000$, $r=\frac{5}{100}$, and the $D$ at $t=0$ is $400000$. So we can calculate the $C$:
$$400000=\frac{40000}{0.05}+C\exp(0 \cdot 0.05)$$
$$400000=800000+C$$
$$C=-400000$$
So the particular solution for your case:
$$D(t)=-400000e^{0.05t}+800000$$
We want to calculate the time required for $D$ to be $0$:
$$0=-400000e^{0.05t}+800000$$
$$400000e^{0.05t}=800000$$
$$e^{0.05t}=2$$
$$0.05t=\log(2)$$
$$t=20 \log(2)$$
So it will take 14 years.

Comment: This is absolutly correct and I got to this step.
But the problem starts here as I cannot calculate the time in which he can repay the loan, can you help me with that?

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash Could you make the text "understandable" for me? I cannot really understand it.

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash I mean what's $P$ and $r$, and what's $D$ at a given time, and what would you like to calculate ($D$ at a given $t$ time, or $t$ from a given $D$ value).

Comment: Oh that, I want to calculate the time when the mortgage gets paid off, So I think its getting a t from a given D value?

Comment: Like this is where I'm getting confused. To calculate the time I will need to calculate the C in any case.
But how to calculate the C? what do I assume D as? Do I even assume it? while P and r are constants but I'm not really understanding the question myself here. Like how is the D working in this question

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash $D$ is a function of the time. $C$ is a constant; you can calculate it's value if you know the $D$'s value at a given $t$ time. For example: We know that the $D$ equals to $D_0$ at the time $t_0$:
$D_0=\frac{P}{r}+C e^{r t_0}$; so the $Ce^{r t_0}=D_0-\frac{P}{r}$;and $C=e^{-r t_0} \left(D_0-\frac{P}{r} \right)$.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that, since $dD/dt$ doesn't depend on the value of $t$, that we can just plug in the known information (i.e. $r$, $P$, and $t$) get that the debt growth ratio and simply divide into $400,000?

Comment: @SeanHenderson I did try that as well, I didn't get any result.

Comment: @Botond I'm thinking of solving this another way
dD/rD-P = dt

Comment: @SeanHenderson $\frac{\mathrm{d}D}{\mathrm{d}t}$ depends on $t$, because $D$ depends on the $t$.

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash The answer will be the same.

Comment: True that. just did.

Comment: @Botond  //  Thank you, that's right.

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash I think I've got it, I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: @SulaimanQizilbash Check it; what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

The equation is separable.

$$dt=\frac{dD}{rD-P}.$$

Then by integration,

$$t=\frac1r\log\left|\frac{rD_t-P}{rD_0-P}\right|$$ and it suffices to set $D_t=0$.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you soo much. Really Ive been stuck on this for hours now.